# Phase in FIR filters

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, filter-design, digital-filters, audio-processing

Does anyone have any idea what is Clear Phase technology ? How is it implemented ? And which audio channels whether left ,right center , sub woofer should have this technology implemented and why?

[Here](https://www.sony.co.in/electronics/car-marine/oem-audio/clear-phase) is the link to its intro.

Can you now please explain this?

Comment: Never heard of "Clear Phase". You don't link to any source for that term, so this stays inanswerable. Clauvunate, you need to get used to the idea that people aren't inside your head, and that the devices, texts and concepts you are looking at aren't universally known and the only way to do something. Please make sure someone who's an expert in their field, but doesn't know the vocabulary you're using, still has a chance of understanding your question. In this case, this would have been easy: link to the website you've found this on, the book or paper.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Sony Trademark. That means it's a marketing term invented by Sony. Verbal descriptions are vague and fluffy: in other words: It can mean pretty much anything they want to including nothing at all.